# how to start emr cluster on amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-emr

I have setup EMR cluster in amazon web service  with 1 master and 2 slaves. I don't know whether I should use start-all.sh command to start the nodes on the cluster. Or, how can I start the EMR cluster nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an EMR Cluster using the AWS console or AWS CLI .

```
aws emr create-cluster \
    --name "1-node dummy cluster" \
    --instance-type m3.xlarge \
    --release-label emr-4.1.0 \
    --instance-count 1 \
    --use-default-roles \
    --applications Name=Spark \
    --auto-terminate
```

There is no need to start the services using start-all.sh. By default all the services will be started automatically . If you want to include any extra services you can add those services using boot strapping.

Comment: I have already created a cluster. When I run jps command, I see "jps, main, StatePusher, MetricsServer".  Since I can't connect ResourceManager or MasterNode  from WEB UI, I don't know whether the nodes are running successfully.

Comment: What do you mean by "MasterNode"? If you mean the Spark Master UI, that is not something that is used with Spark on EMR because Spark is configured to run on YARN. The Spark Master is exclusively for Spark Standalone mode, which is not currently supported on EMR.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I solved my problem. I can see the nodes are running in 'Monitoring' part of the cluster. I thought that there might be a command to start nodes like Hadoop. But there is no need a command to start nodes.